# jQuery slideDown/slideUp laggy animation on Android devices

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, slidedown, slideup

I have problem with jQuery slide animation. I'm trying to make menu which is hiding when user scrolls the page. Here is live example (works only on mobile):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
                $('.section-menu-link').not('.section-menu-link.active').slideUp(300);
            } else {
                $('.section-menu-link').not('.section-menu-link.active').slideDown(300);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.section-menu{
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.section-menu-link{
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.section-menu-link.active{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-menu">
  <a href="#" class="section-menu-link">Link</a>
  <a href="#" class="section-menu-link">Link</a>
  <a href="#" class="section-menu-link active">Link</a>
  <a href="#" class="section-menu-link">Link</a>
  <a href="#" class="section-menu-link">Link</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
</div>
```

It works nice on iOS but on every Android phone I've tested it, animation doesn't work smoothly.

I tried to do it with CSS transition:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
                $('.section-menu').addClass('hide');
            } else {
                $('.section-menu').removeClass('hide');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.section-menu{
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.section-menu.hide .section-menu-link{
    max-height: 0;
}
.section-menu.hide .section-menu-link.active{
    max-height: 30px;
}
.section-menu-link{
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    transition: max-height .3s ease;
}
.section-menu-link.active{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-menu">
<a href="#" class="section-menu-link">Link</a>
<a href="#" class="section-menu-link">Link</a>
<a href="#" class="section-menu-link active">Link</a>
<a href="#" class="section-menu-link">Link</a>
<a href="#" class="section-menu-link">Link</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
</div>
```

But it works as bad as in first example.

Is there any way to make it smoother?

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind that jQuery is **not** specialized on supporting mobile frontend development, so not everything that works in your browser behaves the same way in mobile. Events like click() and scroll() in jQuery will usually get trapped into the mobile browser waiting some milliseconds (this is on purpose to ease mobile browsing) or waiting for some additional event to happen before they trigger.

To get rid of the lag, use touch events instead of click (or desktop) events; for example, replace:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
```

With something similar to:

```
element.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMove, false);
```

As you might have noticed, the code above is not JQuery but plain javascript (you can read more about this on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchmove).

Unfortunately, jQuery doesn't handle touch events by default, so you will either have to use the JavaScript event listener or use an additional library to handle touch events (jQuery Mobile for example, although there are much better choices like https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Touch-Events).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply :) Unfortunately I think my description of the problem wasn't clear enough and you misunderstood what I meant. When menu is sliding down or up, main DIV is changing height and the content is moving down/up (depending on menu height). But it doesn't work smoothly - animation is jumping and lagging.